# How to set up virtual URLs

Tags: php, html, apache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Routing URLs in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095932/routing-urls-in-php)

How do you set up virtual URLs like typical CMS frameworks?  Is there a good tutorial or code bank?  From what I understand it reroutes all requests to the index.php and Apache does some sort of mod_rewrite.  I'm not totally sure though.  How would I start setting up a framework like this?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct with the mod_rewrite, here is a couple of good tutorials on the matter, it also goes into various other uses of the .htaccess file

http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite

Answer (score 0):

You should enable mod_rewrite in Apache.

You are right about rerouting all requests to index.php

Once your done with all of that your .htaccess file should contain something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

This basically tells all request to go to index.php

I would suggest checking out existing frameworks like CodeIgniter and find out how they do it, then implement your own.

Comment: It's not necessary to send all requests to `index.php`.

Comment: Well of course by "all", I mean excluding images and other stuff like my htaccess example code.

Comment: Sure. But what you're proposing is the [front controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) which is an extreme case of URL redirection. In many cases, it makes more sense to have several rewrite rules for different parts of the application.

Comment: Yup that's exactly what I'm proposing. Isn't that what's being done in most MVCs, why is that bad?

Comment: Not saying it's necessarily bad. I would just suggest the answer isn't complete without explaining this.

Comment: +1 as I am not sure why it was downvoted. Perfectly reasonable answer, imo.

Answer (score 0):

See how symfony does it [here](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.0/data/skeleton/project/web/.htaccess) (as far as the mod_rewrite goes).

And check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115629/simplest-php-routing-framework) for some ways to do the PHP part.