# .htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have this error when trying to browse php files locally

```
[Fri Apr 13 19:16:40 2012] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/AppServ/www/hr-website/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://127.0.0.1/
```

what is the problem ?

Comment: You don't have the mod_rewrite module installed.

Comment: `ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load`

Comment: Nowadays on Ubuntu you can run `a2enmod rewrite` which is a shortcut for creating the symbolic link - http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/a2enmod.8.html

Answer (score 435, accepted):

> or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Check to make sure you have `mod_rewrite` enabled.

From: https://webdevdoor.com/php/mod_rewrite-windows-apache-url-rewriting

1. Find the httpd.conf file (usually you will find it in a folder called conf, config or something along those lines)
2. Inside the httpd.conf file uncomment the line LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so (remove the pound '#' sign from in front of the line)
3. Also find the line ClearModuleList is uncommented then find and make sure that the line AddModule mod_rewrite.c is not commented out.

If the `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` line is missing from the httpd.conf file entirely, just add it.

#### Sample command

To enable the module in a standard ubuntu do this:

```
a2enmod rewrite
systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: I've already uncommented LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so .. but the same error

Comment: @Bader dont forget to restart apache

Comment: this did it for me. I was so frustrated until I bumped into this answer. I think this error must be common for users who had recently install php.

Comment: Don't forget `sudo` if not logged in as root.
`sudo a2enmod rewrite` and `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Answer (score 587):

Under [Apache 2+](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/) you can simply do as below (Using Linux Terminal):

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite && sudo service apache2 restart
```

or

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite && sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: +1, this is a better solution because it doesn't require you to edit any files, but rather use a command that is built into apache2.

Comment: I have this problem for the whole day and this one fixed it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 50):

Just Follow Simple 1-2-3 Steps :

> 1) Go to Taskbar
>
> 2) Click on WAMP icon (Left Click)

[image]

> 3) Now Go to Apache > Services > Apache Module and check Rewrite_module is enable or not 
>   ! if its not then click on it ! WAMP will be automatically restarted and you're done !

[image]

Answer (score 16):

This comment from [verybadbug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661843/verybadbug) under question helped me:

```
ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load
```

After that we need restart Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: It's important to say that the command suggested above:
`sudo a2enmod rewrite && sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`
does exactly this that you suggested.

Answer (score 15):

I can see that your using AppServ, mod_rewrite is disabled by default on that WAMP package (just googled it)

**Solution:**

Find: `C:/AppServ/Apache/conf/httpd.conf` file.

and un-comment this line
`#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

**Restart apache...**
Simplez

Answer (score 5):

If you are working with PHP-FPM on Ubuntu you might have created your own conf file under `/etc/apache2/sites-available/domain.conf`
First check if you have installed and enabled rewrite engine or not. If it is not enabled please run following command -

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

This will enable the rewrite engine.
After this put following line in your `domain.conf` file after directory structure -

```
RewriteEngine On
```

And at the last don't forget to restart the Apache service by running following command -

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: sudo a2enmod rewrite - fixed the issue for me! I was turning it  on by writing AllowOverride ALL from apache2.conf file, but it still didn't work. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

Also make sure php is enabled by uncommenting the

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

line that comes right after

```
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
```

Make sure both those lines in

```
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

are uncommented.

Comment: this has nothing to do with PHP or the php5_module. `a2enmod rewrite` is the needed command

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred for me because mod_rewrite was not enabled.
Everything worked fine after enabling the rewrite module:
https://www.debuntu.org/how-to-enable-apache-modules-under-debian-based-system-page-2/

Answer (score 0):

Steps to start Apache httpd.exe (I am using x64 VC11 example here)

```
http://www.apachelounge.com/download/VC11/
```

Be sure that you have installed Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 : VC11 vcredist_x64/86.exe

```
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679
```

You may need to have Visual Studio 2012 Update 3 (VS2012.3)

```
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679 (vcredirect.exe)
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2835600
```

Unzip httpd-2.4.4-win64-VC11.zip and copy paste in

```
C:\Apache24
```

Unzip modules-2.4-win64-VC11.zip and copy paste them in

```
C:\Apache24\modules

http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=25091
```

For further info on the modules see the Apache Lounge VC10 Win64 download page and/or the readme in the .zip's there.

```
http://www.apachelounge.com/download/win64/
```

In

```
C:\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf
```

un-comment (remove # sign) starting below this like copy pasted list in here

```
# Example:
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so

LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_socache_module modules/mod_authn_socache.so
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authz_dbd_module modules/mod_authz_dbd.so
LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule buffer_module modules/mod_buffer.so
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
LoadModule data_module modules/mod_data.so
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule heartbeat_module modules/mod_heartbeat.so
LoadModule heartmonitor_module modules/mod_heartmonitor.so
LoadModule ident_module modules/mod_ident.so
LoadModule imagemap_module modules/mod_imagemap.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
LoadModule lbmethod_bybusyness_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so
LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
LoadModule lbmethod_bytraffic_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bytraffic.so
LoadModule lbmethod_heartbeat_module modules/mod_lbmethod_heartbeat.so
LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule log_debug_module modules/mod_log_debug.so
LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
LoadModule lua_module modules/mod_lua.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_express_module modules/mod_proxy_express.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_html_module modules/mod_proxy_html.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
LoadModule ratelimit_module modules/mod_ratelimit.so
LoadModule reflector_module modules/mod_reflector.so
LoadModule remoteip_module modules/mod_remoteip.so
LoadModule request_module modules/mod_request.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule sed_module modules/mod_sed.so
LoadModule session_module modules/mod_session.so
LoadModule session_cookie_module modules/mod_session_cookie.so
LoadModule session_crypto_module modules/mod_session_crypto.so
LoadModule session_dbd_module modules/mod_session_dbd.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule slotmem_plain_module modules/mod_slotmem_plain.so
LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so
LoadModule socache_dbm_module modules/mod_socache_dbm.so
LoadModule socache_memcache_module modules/mod_socache_memcache.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule watchdog_module modules/mod_watchdog.so
LoadModule xml2enc_module modules/mod_xml2enc.so
```

Then find

```
C:\Apache24\bin\ApacheMonitor.exe
```

and double click on it.

Then in Command Prompt (CMD.exe) type

```
C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe
```

and press enter. It shows any error remaining.

Build with the latest Update 3 Visual Studio® 2012 aka VC11. VC11 has improvements, fixes and optimizations over VC10 in areas like Performance, MemoryManagement and Stability. For example code quality tuning and improvements done across different code generation areas for "speed". And makes more use of modern processors and win7, win8, 2008 and Server 2012 internal features.

The VC11 binaries loads VC11, VC10 and VC9 modules, and does not run on XP and 2003. Minimum system required: Windows 7 SP1, Windows 8 / 8.1, Windows Vista SP2, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Server 2012 / R2

After you have downloaded and before you attempt to install it, you should make sure that it is intact and has not been tampered with. Use the PGP Signature and/or the SHA Checksums to verify the integrity.

Thank you