# Apache2 WWW remove FAIL with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2, no-www

I want to ***remove "www"*** from my domain at apache2.
I tryed out lots of examples whiches do it with an `.htaccess` file but none of them works.
So here's my `.htacces` which is owned by user root with chmod 644:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^your-site.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://your-site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This is not removing the www <del>and if I type `http://your-site.com` in my browser (Firefox) it redirects me to `www.your-domain.com` stil.</del> **EDIT: It was browser's fail, but prev. problem exists.**

My apache2 is setted up for this main domain without `www.` already and that was my all .htaccess.

Comment: Do you have other rules? Or a CMS or some other framework? Because your rules do not add a `www`.

Comment: No this is my all .htaccess, and i don't have cms, only normal php files in a directory. Anyway i found, the force www. was my browser's fail but it still doesn't remove www if i open with www.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy solution I use from [No WWW, Better SEO](http://alantait.net/2012/07/21/no-www-better-seo/) is to start each .htaccess with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# FROM www. --TO-- NO www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is just a cut and paste no brainer.  It is the first thing on each .htaccess I have on hundreds of sites and domains.

Answer (score 1):

Find the error in apache log:

Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

So the problem were apache2 was misconfigured...

Solved with command: sudo a2enmod rewrite
from this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11649987/1725341