# Web server not reading .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I have Ubuntu 12.10 with apache2 installed, and my .htaccess file is not working. I have it set up to be able to not have .php file extensions in the links, so it looks like www.website.com/login instead of /login.php, but it says that the URL "/login" is not found on the server. I have read [this page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-htaccess/) and it says something about "AllowOverride All" but I don't know where that is, or if I need to add it, where I would add it.

**EDIT:** I have found [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingUseOfApacheHtaccessFiles) and have found what it says, but it says that I have an Internal Server Error on any page I go to. I have changed the  to

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

but it says Internal Server Error

**EDIT #2:** In the error log, it says

```
/var/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

**EDIT #3:** Found the answer here: [.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144634/htaccess-invalid-command-rewriteengine-perhaps-misspelled-or-defined-by-a-m)

Comment: You have to search for a file called `httpd.conf`. Also it would be nice if you provided some code.

Comment: I'm not sure, but doesn't apache2 not have httpd.conf?

Comment: I've Apache 2.2.22 and it has httpd.conf, have you tried to search for it ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried, but it came up with nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure you have enabled mod_rewrite in your .htaccess.

Also make sure you these lines at the top of your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

i.e. turn the `MultiViews` options off.

Also see **[this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755169/mod-rewrite-is-enabled-but-not-working/16755191#16755191)** for a similar problem and my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should have or specify Directory-block in your apache configurations. You can find `AllowOverride` documentation here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride

And documentation about `<Directory>` is here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory

In short: specify where you would like to allow the settings to be overridden with `<Directory /path/to/your/directory>` and then use `AllowOverride all` in that directory block.

Comment: So I put this at the bottom of the config file:

    `<Directory />
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>`
And it's still not working

Comment: It should be the path on the filesystem.