# I want to Get .htaccess file Content through Url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using this function to get content of .htaccess file

```
file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/.htaccess')
```

But its give me this error

```
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

But When i open this url its working fine

```
file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/robots.txt')
```

Please help me to solved this Problem.

Thanks

Comment: I think that this isn't possible, because this would be a security problem.

Comment: if you want to read it at your website, you can use a php like a proxy to read the .htaccess file content.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753107/web-server-not-reading-htaccess-file

Comment: @user1577168 you can get it with simple service. See my answer

Comment: You can expose the content of your own `.htaccess` file - is that what you're trying to do? If you're trying to get the contents of an external `.htaccess` file, that's not going to be possible unless they provided a means of doing so.

Comment: I have 10 different sites and i want to show htaccess content of all of my sites in my API without login in Server.

Comment: Big question is **WHY**? What are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: So you can implement what @HüseyinBABAL has done on each of those 10 websites. Beware however that If you make a request from the client to those proxies that anyone can get the password / whatever.

Comment: I want to check if any one edit htaccess file.

Comment: @user1577168 make your htaccess readonly

Answer (score 3):

The default configuration for any HTTP server that supports `.htaccess` configuration files is to *not* expose them over HTTP.

At best, the details of the server's configuration are not something the public needs to know about and, at worst, could be a serious security problem if exposed to the public.

You could look in to reconfiguring the server to make the `.htaccess` files public, but you would be better served accessing the file using the file system instead of HTTP.

Comment: I want to show content of .htaccess file in my API. Is there any way to show content of .htaccess file?. Without login in to server.

Comment: Your reasons for wanting to access the file don't change anything about this answer. It still holds.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get content through web, but you can access it with simple service;

**htaccess.php**

```
<?php

$password = $_GET["pass"]; // password protection

if(!empty($password) && $password == "your_password") {
    $file = 'path/to/.htaccess'; //physical path on server

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        echo file_get_contents( $file );
    }
}
```

And go to

```
http://your_domain.com/htaccess.php?pass=your_password
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to extend Quentin's answer:

`.htaccess` is a file by your server to tell the system how to handle HTTP requests such ass file and folder access. It is ill recommended to have that exposed to an outside requester unless in 2 condition:

1) within a CMS file manager in this case it should display it to you so that you can edit the file (like cpanel or directadmin)

2) FTP.

calling it externally...no.