# Invalid Command 'ReWriteEngine'

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

First off, before somebody posts this link, I will tell you I have looked through it and tried what it said to no avail. [.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144634/htaccess-invalid-command-rewriteengine-perhaps-misspelled-or-defined-by-a-m)

I am using Codeigniter on a website and am attempting to get rid of the index.php in the URL. This code has been added to the .htaccess file in the root of my website.

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

When I test it I get a 500 internal server error. Checking the error logs is says "Invalid Command 'RewriteEngine'". In the mods-enabled folder rewrite.load is listed. Also, I have restarted Apache after enabling rewrite.

Spent a few hours messing around with this and still have the same problem. Thanks in advance.

Source for .htaccess code: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Comment: Did you remember to restart Apache after enabling mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 1):

`"Invalid Command 'Rewrite Engine'"`

Are you *sure* you don't have a space between "Rewrite" and "Engine" here? The htaccess syntax is not very forgiving when it comes to whitespace and having "Rewrite Engine" will definitely make it break.

Comment: Positive, that is copied straight from the file, which was originally copied from codeigniter's website. Just to be sure though I just checked.

Comment: I'd have to agree with +Jon Lin that the error containing a space sounds odd and might be a tell at what is going on.  Though if you've checked the .htaccess file I'm not sure where else to tell you to look.

Answer (score 1):

There was an error starting Apache and when it was fixed everything worked. Thanks for the help anyway.