# Apache Rewrite rules not working as expected

Tags: apache, .htaccess, zend-framework, mod-rewrite, ubuntu

I have two apache servers both have identical settings, I cloned the apache config files, and changed the ServerName part only. When I type mysite.com/somestuff it should rewrite to index.php it does it on my old server, but not my new. I have made sure the .htaccess is there when I do mysite.com/index.php/somestuff it works, but like my first site I need it to work with mysite.com/somestuff.

I am really banging my head against the wall here is my .htaccess and apache config file

```
#.htaccess file
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{CONTEXT_PREFIX}/$2 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}index.php/ [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

Now for my apache config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin user@host.com
        ServerName mysite.com
        DocumentRoot /home/richardw/www/halogen/web
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/richardw/www/halogen/web/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My apologizes if this is a repost, but I've been searching all over and i'm about to lose it.

Comment: When you go to `http://mysite.com/`, are you redirected to `http://mysite.com/index.php/`?

Answer (score 2):

> When you go to `http://mysite.com/`, are you redirected to `http://mysite.com/index.php/`?

If this is happening, that means mod_rewrite is not loaded in your new server. You need to make sure it's loaded in your apache's server config file. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10144709/851273) for some instructions on how that works for apache.

The reason why the redirect is working is because of this container:

```
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

This essentially says "if mod_rewrite is **not** loaded", then if mod_alias is loaded, it redirects the root request to `/index.php/`. So if the redirect is happening, mod_rewrite is **not** loaded.

Comment: Yep that was it :/. I swear I did this, but i had missed typed it. 

ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to comment or remove this line
`Options +FollowSymlinks`

in your .htaccess?