# htaccess rewrite subdomains to 1 file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I am helping someone with their site and they want a template page (example.com/template) shown on each of their subdomains.

So when a user navigates to `a.example.com` or `b.example.com`, etc.
they see `example.com/template.php` 
but the url stays `a.example.com`or `b.example.com`, etc.

I know there is a way to do this I just can't figure it out.
Basically I want to be able to change all of the pages at once by making a change to 1 file.

I think I am close with this code but I keep get 500 errors
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^$.example.com$ [NC]`
`RewriteRule ^$ $1.example.com/template.php`


PS: these are actual domains, not virtual

This is what I currently have

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.+\.dfwfamilylifenews\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /template.php [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure the rewrite module is loaded in Apache. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10144709/851273) for more info.

Second, you need to change your rules to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.+\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /template.php [L]
```

Comment: Cloud hosted by DirectAdmin.com. I am unable to check the http.conf file, although he is running wordpress and they have their custom rules already in place, so I am pretty sure it is loaded.

Comment: I am still not getting to the template.php page. I am still navigating to the actual subdomain.

Comment: @BenMiller Make sure those rules are before any wordpress rules or any other kind of routing rules