# How do I get mod_rewrite working on Heroku?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, heroku

I'm trying to rewrite a URL using the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /curation.php?id=$1 [L]
```

and this is an .htaccess file I created:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /curation.php?id=$1 [L]
```

but when I push it to my Heroku server, I get a 500 Internal Server Error on all pages. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you may not have mod_rewrite loaded on the server

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how do I load mod_rewrite on the server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144634/htaccess-invalid-command-rewriteengine-perhaps-misspelled-or-defined-by-a-m/10144709#10144709

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem is you rewrite rule

try something like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+) index.php?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have mod_rewrite loaded, and your rules are in an htaccess file in your document root. The rules that you have are causing an infinite loop. You need to add a condition or two to prevent that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/curation\.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /curation.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /curation.php?id=$1 [L]
```