# codeigniter localhost internal server error 500

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, wamp

I am starting a new project in codeigniter. While setting up work folder in localhost i put the following htaccess file in my project root folder for remove index.php from the url

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?/$1
```

now i am getting the error message as follows

"Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."

my project path is localhost/sc

in the config.php file
i put the following line

```
 $config['base_url']='http://localhost/sc';
```

server error message is " Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration"

I am using wamp server in windows platform
please help me to solve this problem

Thank you

Comment: have you enabled rewrite module in apache?

Comment: yes i do it now ..but now page not found error!!
when i am not using index.php in the url ...is there any problem with the .htaccess file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This .htaccess script works perfectly for me. Place it within the first set of folders inside your project directory. Same level as the index.php file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

The error 500 can be checked on the apache error.log file using the following path /var/log/apache2/error.log

Check the last error listed and fix it.

Comment: Perfect text for .htaccess, Thanks !

Comment: your last line (check the error logs), which most of the beginners might have ignored... is the most useful part in your answer...

Answer (score 5):

See this question: [.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144634/htaccess-invalid-command-rewriteengine-perhaps-misspelled-or-defined-by-a-m/10144709#10144709)

Essentially, you need to turn on mod_rewrite. That's why you're getting the `" Invalid command 'RewriteEngine'` error message.

Additionally, since you're project path is in `/sc/` you need to set you base to `/sc/`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sc/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?/$1
```

And place the htaccess file in the `/sc/` folder.

Answer (score 3):

Activate a rewrite_module in your WAMP. It comes disabled by default

Answer (score 2):

> I had the same issue a year ago. 1. First and foremost, make sure that mod_rewrite module is enabled in your apache server ( Apache -> Apache Modules -> Rewrite_module [Just select] Or else See "Apache error log" under Apache Menu in wampserver to know more about the error). Don't waste time for other solution.

## 2. Secondly, that might be because of htaccess rules. Kindly, use this basic line of code for htaccess.

```html
 Options +FollowSymlinks RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

In CodeIgniter, If you are calling a model that tries to fetch values from a table that doesn't exist, you may face a 500 - internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

Activate Rewrite_module in wampserver
Like Apache -> Apache Modules -> Rewrite_module [Just select]
Or else
See "Apache error log" under Apache Menu in wampserver to know more about the error