# URL Rewrite giving 500 internal error

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to perform a URL Rewrite but giving me a 500 Internal Server Error

I have an `index.php` file that can take a parameter which I called `cmd` so the URL should look like:

`http://localhost/some_folder/index.php?cmd=some_parameter`

What I'm trying to achieve is allowing users to just type any of the following:

`http://localhost/some_folder/some_parameter`

OR

`http://localhost/some_folder/index/some_parameter`

Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^index.php/?$    index.php?cmd=shifts    [NC,L]
```

I also tried:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule /cmd/(.*)/ index.php?cmd=$1
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong here!

Comment: My tummy tells me that the first `.htaccess` snippet seems to be creating an infinite loop of rewrites. For instance, if you request `/index.php?cmd=test`, it will be rewritten to `/index.php?cmd=shifts`... and as the rule still applies, it'll be rewritten *again* to `/index.php?cmd=shifts`. This goes on until the limit of internal redirects is reached.

Comment: There is an apache error log that will tell you what the problem is. In ubuntu it is usually at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I found this error `Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

Comment: it is shown as an alert

Comment: In my answer below, I have managed to somehow do it. But still on a single page, I'm getting an error!!

Answer (score 1):

> I found this error Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

You need to load mod_rewrite. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10144709/851273) for details for how to fix.

Comment: Ok, I loaded the module and now I'm not getting any errors .. But the rewriting is not working!!

Comment: Can you check my answer below? It still gives me error with the rootFolder only!!

Answer (score 0):

After lots of searching on the internet and especially stackoverflow, I reached a solution (not what I wanted, but it is working for now until I find another one that suits my needs better.

Here is the `.htaccess` that I'm using at the moment (actually I'm using 2 files as each folder/sub-folder got different parameters):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /rootFolder # In the sub-folder I type /rootFolder/subFolder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule /cmd/(.*)/ index.php?R=$1 # In the sub-folder I type index.php?cmd=$1
```

Now I access using the URL `http://localhost/rootFolder/index/R/xxx-1234` and `http://localhost/rootFolder/admin/index/cmd/xxx`

What I need to do is remove the `index` portion of the URL.