# Getting internal error 500 instead of 404 Apache rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I wrote this in my .htaccess file inside my include folder but instead of getting a 404 error message I am getting a 500 internal server error message. How do I change this to a 404 error message?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^includes(/|/.+)?$ - [R=404,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have mod_rewrite turned on. Make sure the rewrite module is loaded in your server config, should be a line that looks something like:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

or something similar (uncommented). Also see: [.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144634/htaccess-invalid-command-rewriteengine-perhaps-misspelled-or-defined-by-a-m/10144709#10144709)