# getting 500 server error trying to remove trailing backslashes in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I hardly ever work with htaccess, so maybe it's obvious what I am doing wrong, but I found this line of code which supposedly removed trailing backslashes:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301]
```

only, since I added it I always get a 500 internal server error. in fact any rewriteRule causes this error. Below I will put the entire content of my .htaccess file (it's only 3 lines). If anyone can see what might be causing this error, I would be very grateful to know. I am using an Apache 2.4.4 server and working as localhost. Thanks.

```
RemoveHandler .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301]
```

Comment: What are the errors in your Apache error log? You may not have the rewrite module added or you don't have permission to add the rewrite rule in the place you have.

Comment: I'm not sure where that log is located

Comment: What operating system are you using? On Linux it's typically located in `/var/log/httpd`

Comment: If you're using shared hosting, then you can find the error log in your console, e.g. cPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like mod_rewrite isn't loaded. You need to edit your httpd.conf (or maybe it's called apache.conf) and make sure this line is uncommented:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

See also: [.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144634/htaccess-invalid-command-rewriteengine-perhaps-misspelled-or-defined-by-a-m/10144709#10144709)

Comment: Yes, you should have `RewriteEngine On` before any rewrites, and you might need `<IfModule rewrite_mod.c>` around it, depending on the server setup.

Comment: thank you that was it, and now its fixed. Thanks for spotting that, Like I wrote in the post,I am htaccess challenged.

Answer (score 1):

It is is due to directories getting slash added by `mod_dir`:

Try this rule to avid 500:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

And test in a different browser to avoid 301 caching.