# .htaccess giving me 500 internal server error while the RewriteCond is very simple

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm new to .htaccess files, I've been watching tutorials online and everything seems perfect, but right now I'm trying to clean up the URL, so if user enters `/products...` he is redirected to `products.php`.

Here's the .htaccess code:

```
ReweriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} products/
RewriteRule products/ http://localhost/website/products.php
```

It's too simple but driving me crazy, so any idea?

Here's the error log:

```
[Tue Aug 26 18:28:20 2014] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/AppServ/www/website/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Comment: Check your apache error.log to see what is causing 500

Comment: [Tue Aug 26 18:28:20 2014] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/AppServ/www/website/.htaccess: Invalid command 'ReweriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: That means `mod_rewrite` isn't enabled in Apache config

Comment: Just change  `ReweriteEngine on` to `RewriteEngine on`

Comment: @Regent i just did change it and here's the error again 

[Tue Aug 26 18:44:26 2014] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/AppServ/www/website/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: Well, all that I can suggest is to read [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine) about it.

Comment: Doing a google search for "**Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration**" returns this as the first result: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144634/htaccess-invalid-command-rewriteengine-perhaps-misspelled-or-defined-by-a-m

Answer (score 0):

simply , configure WAMP apache modyle :

1- left click on WAMP icon on taskbar.
2- Click Apache > Apache Modules.
3- you will find in the list "rewrite module" unchecked , check it and DONE (Y)