# still get 500 internal server error appserv

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using Appserv Apache and i when i use .htaccess file i still getting 500 internal server error ...
I tried every thing and made sure that every thing is correct and I'm removed the # from the httpd.conf file : LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so ..... 
and restarted the Appserv .. 
but i still getting 500 internal server error .. any help ??
this is the .htaccess :-
Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /mvc/public

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: The error **LOG**, not the error **PAGE**.

Comment: Do you have `AllowOverride All` in your http.conf?

Comment: And no error when you delete this .htacces file ? Did you send the file in text mode ?

Comment: AllowOverride All is enabled .. yes.no error when i delete this .htacces file..

Comment: You can read the page `http://www.domain.com/mvc/public/index.php?url=xxx` ?

Comment: error log : Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: Croises : no it gives me the same result

Comment: Change for `RewriteBase /mvc/public/`. But I think mod_rewrite don't work... try to reboot or restart Apache.

Answer (score 0):

> error log : Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

THis means you don't have mod_rewrite enabled in your server. See: [.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144634/htaccess-invalid-command-rewriteengine-perhaps-misspelled-or-defined-by-a-m/10144709#10144709)

You need to either turn it on using

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite && sudo service apache2 restart
```

if you're using ubuntu, or edit your `httpd.conf` file and uncomment the mod rewrite line.