# .htaccess configuration for HTML5 History API

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, html5-history

After several days of digging at the HTML5 History API, I found this great working example that suits my needs https://github.com/pinceladasdaweb/html5-history-api

However, when trying to run it on my local server/web hosting, I get an **Internal Server Error**, which leads me to think that there's something misconfigured in the .htacccess file.

Looked up at the Apache Error log and confirmed my theory, this was what error line tells:

> "[...]
>   .../html5-history-api-master/.htaccess:
>   Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a
>   module not included in the server configuration"

I'd like to know if I need to make specific configurations in the server to make the example run properly.

You can see a working demo done by the owner here: http://www.pinceladasdaweb.com.br/html5-history-api/

Any help will be really appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: No, you don't need any specific changes in .htaccess to change the browsers history from the clientside

Comment: Thanks adeneo! Do you know what would be happening then?

Comment: I say this all the time. **Stop trying to guess what's wrong**. That form of troubleshooting will lead your to hours of frustration. Just simply check your Apache `error_log` file and it will tell you exactly why there is a 500 error. That's what its for. No body will just know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have done to make it work.

1- As Panama Jack said in the comments, the answer of what was happening was in the log file **wamp\logs\apache_error.log**

*[...] /html5-history-api-master/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration*

2- I enabled the **rewrite_module** on my local server (see Hardik Thaker for your visual reply to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144634/htaccess-invalid-command-rewriteengine-perhaps-misspelled-or-defined-by-a-m)!

3- My web hosting is GoDaddy, I found out that I had to tweak the .htaccess file to make it work. [This last post](http://davidwalsh.name/mod_rewrite-htaccess-godaddy) saved my life!

Hope it helps!