# PHP: AJAX: Get: incorrect URL

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache

I'm moving my application to new server, and have been hitting into some issues lately.
PHP `version: 5.5.34`, Mac OSX Apache `2.4`

Laravel version: `4.2`

I get a grid but my browser complains for URL.

My ajax requests looks like:

`$(grid_name).jqGrid({`

```
    //to get this function working make sure you've .htaccess file  
    //url:'illumina_xhr_get_data', - won't work if not added illumina 
    url:"illumina/illumina_xhr_get_samples",
    //url:"illumina/illumina_xhr_get_samples",
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: "GET",
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        id: "",
        root:  function (obj) {
            return obj;
        },
        records: function (obj) {
            return obj.length;
        },
        page: function () {
            return 1;
        },
        total: function () {
            return 1;
        }
    },

    colNames:['Study','Sample Name','Forward Primer',
            'Reverse Primer','Region','Read Length','Seq Platform', "ID"], //id is hidden.. that is used while making group
    colModel :[ 
               {name:"study_name",sortable: true}, 
               {name: "sample_name",sortable: false},
               {name: "forward_primer",sortable: false},
               {name: "reverse_primer",sortable: false},
               {name:"region",sortable:false},
               {name:"read_length",sortable:false,align:'right'},
               {name:"seq_platform",sortable:false},
               {name:"id",sortable:false,hidden:true}

               ],
        rowNum:10, //this sets the default row in the pager
        caption:"Illumina", //title of the grid
        pager: pager_name,  
        shrinkToFit : false,
        rownumbers: true, //row numbers on left
        multiselect: true, //check box
        height: '400', //height: 'auto',
        width: '1100',
        gridview: true,         
        viewrecords:true, // this is for the View 1 - 8 of 8 \m/
        sortorder:"asc", //asc 
        autoencode: true, //don't know
        sortable:true, //sort
        loadonce: true, //loadonce is must
        rowList:[500,1000,1500], //drop down
        page: 1,
        rowNum: 100,
        ignoreCase: true, //make search as case insenstive -- YAY.. Party
        grouping:true, //this is for grouping
        groupingView : { groupField : ['study_name'], //grouping based on study column
            groupText : ['<b>{0} - {1} Sample(s)</b>'] //this will give count of samples present
             } ///grouping view ends
});
```

`

Error:

`The requested URL  /pims/public/illumina/illumina_xhr_get_samples  was not found on this server.`

My local host points to `~/Sites`

The same code works on my other machine (from which I'm transitioning).

I'm unable to figure out a solution to this. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution from: [.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144634/htaccess-invalid-command-rewriteengine-perhaps-misspelled-or-defined-by-a-m)

I'd to enable re-write module in order to be it read by server.

I found error in `/var/log/apache2/error_log`

Hope it helps someone. Thank you.