# PHP Server Error 500

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have used XAMPP in my local machine. My PHP Version 5.2.4. I want to get value from URL.

index.php(C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPJ)

```
preg_match("/[^\/]+$/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],$match);
echo $match[0];
```

when i navigate **localhost:70/phpj/** then **No** output will be displayed.

but i try to navigate **localhost:70/phpj/abcdef** then generate an **Object not found! Error 404**

when i type like **localhost:70/phpj/?abcdef** then output **?abcdef**

I also write .htaccess file in **PHPJ** directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I checked my Apache error log

> [Sat Sep 24 16:13:01 2016] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1]
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/PHPJ/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine',
>   perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server
>   configuration
>
> ---

My goal is to when i type **localhost:70/phpj/abcdef** then index file give me output like **abcdef**

---

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144634/htaccess-invalid-command-rewriteengine-perhaps-misspelled-or-defined-by-a-m)

Comment: You don't have the mod_rewrite module installed. Possible duplicate of stackoverflow.com/questions/10144634/htaccess-invalid-command-rewriteengine-perhaps-misspelled-or-defined-by-a-m