# error in .htacces file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm new to this website thing. I wrote a .htaccess file and enabled the mod_rewrite.

But still i get the same error in my error.log file.

This error is on my live website but not when i run it locally on my PC.

Anyone please help.

.htaccess file

live website

directory

This is my error.log

i have done the "sudo a2enmod rewrite" .

and mod rewrite isinstalled.

Comment: Is mod_rewrite installed?
Also, googling the error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144634/htaccess-invalid-command-rewriteengine-perhaps-misspelled-or-defined-by-a-m

Comment: Have you restarted the apache service?

Comment: yup ...but stiill the problem persists

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve]. You should especially not provide screenshots of your code. Provide it as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installation of mod rewrite restart your services then to check if mod rewrite is enabled and used add this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ mod_rewrite.php
```

Then create file `mod_rewrite.php` and add this and run it

```
<?php echo "Success"; ?>
```

If is not enabled open `httpd.conf` (Apache Config file) and look for this line, remove `#`, save the file and reload apache again.

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Comment: but there's no
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

in the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Comment: Please refer and check this thread may help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48362/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-in-apache