# URL as an ID to retrieve page contents

Tags: php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a long experience using old techniques in web development, like class ASP, I previously developed a news website long years ago. Now, i want to upgrade it using more advanced techniques (I have strong backgrounds to to re-learn PHP and ASP.Net).
My question is:
I used to retrieve a page content from database through an ID, like this:

```
mywebsite.com/NewsID.asp?ID=101
```

But, I see most websites now use different URL, like BBC today, for example:

```
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-latin-america-24680283
```

How to do this?! i.e. not to make my URL like this of BBC not as my classic one

Comment: I'm unsure, but if you're using Apache, you may follow [this guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).

Comment: You have tagged php and asp.net mvc. Is your question related to how in php or in asp.net mvc?

Comment: The answer would be different for each of the 3 technologies you tagged (PHP, ASP.NET, and ASP.NET MVC). You should pick the one most relevant to what you are trying to do. This URL behavior is built-in to ASP.NET MVC, if you check out any basic MVC tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do so by using routes, that is ways to tell your web server (or other equivalent component) to interpret

```
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-latin-america-24680283
```

via a regex or similar tool, to mean

```
Function name: news
Slug: world-latin-america-
Id: 24680283
```

And then invoke, for example

```
news.php?id=24680283
```

or

```
public ActionResult News(long id, string slug)
{
   //
}
```

In a LAMP system, routes can be set by using `mod_rewrite` as documented in [Routing URLs in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095932/routing-urls-in-php).

In an ASP.Net MVC context [routes are set](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs) by calling `RegisterRoutes` in `Application_Start()` in your `Global.asax.cs`.

In the latest version of MVC, you can also use a [`RouteAttribute`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx) that makes everything simpler:

```
[Route("news/{slug}-{id:int}")]
public ActionResult News(int id) { ... }
```